# Is there a function to create a list of unique elements in unique index using python?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to create a new set of lists of elements, with each element of the original list in a unique index in the following lists?

```
orginal_list=['r', 'g', 'b', 'y']

output: ['y', 'g', 'r', 'b'],['g', 'y', 'b', 'r'],['r', 'b', 'y', 'g'],['b', 'r', 'g', 'y']
or
output: ['y', 'r', 'b', 'g'],['g', 'y', 'r', 'b'],['r', 'b', 'g', 'y'],['b', 'g', 'y', 'r']
or 
...
```

I have tried to use `iterators.permutations`, but this does not fit with the unique index requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be to rotate the list. Here is a simple generator function producing all such rotations:

```
def rots(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        yield lst[i:] + lst[:i]

>>> list(rots(['r', 'g', 'b', 'y']))
[['r', 'g', 'b', 'y'], 
 ['g', 'b', 'y', 'r'], 
 ['b', 'y', 'r', 'g'], 
 ['y', 'r', 'g', 'b']]
```

The rotating guarantees that each element actually occurs in each index exactly once.